# C# Generate graph/chart of depedancies?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for a tool. I have many classes in a C# project all within a namespace. I'd like to get a chart or list of dependencies. I want a print out of every class and all the classes that depend on it to the right of it

Its hard to explain why i want this. Its for me and not for my code. I know i can use reflection to write a tool but i rather not atm.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's overkill for your requirements but NDepend has a dependecy matrix which outputs a graph of the results:

http://www.ndepend.com/

James

Answer (score 1):

You could always try having a look at the new version of AutoDiagrammer by Sacha Barber on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207280/200-Reflective-Class-Diagram-Creation-Tool

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate version includes this function which can scan and output the list of dependencies. Just click the menu of visual studio: Architecture -> Generate Dependency Graph

Answer (score 0):

The built-in Object Browser already somewhat does this, right?